# Stata and SPSS regression results different

Tags: regression, spss, stata

I am using Stata with a simple dataset to do very basic regressions and comparing with SPSS to see if the results are the same, but they're not. I'm close, the significance are slightly the same, while  the magnitudes of the betas are completely different. The data was copy and pasted into each from an Excel.
can anyone help?

[![SPSS Regression Result][1]][1]

REGRESSION
/MISSING LISTWISE
/STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
/CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
/NOORIGIN
/DEPENDENT ETR
/METHOD=ENTER Leverage lnAssets Capitalintensive ROA ESG LnGdp.

```
       Var. |   Unst.B | Std.Err. |   St.B |    t    | Sig.
 (Constant) |  0.275   |   0.019  |        |  14.578 | .000
   Leverage |  0.000   |   0.000  | -0.058 | -6.825  | .000
   Ln Assets|  0.003   |   0.001  |  0.025 | -2.531  | .011
  caoitalINt|  0.028   |   0.005  |  0.046 |  5.628  | .000
       ROA  | -0.007   |   0.000  | -0.277 | -31.879 | .000
       Esg  |  0.000   |   0.000  |  0.058 |  6.549  | .000
      Ln GDP|  0.000   |   0.001  |  0.045 |  5.490  | .000
```

Stata Regression Result

. reg etr esg leverage lnassets capitalintensive roa lngdp

[![Stata Regression Result][2]][2]

```
          ETR   |     Coef. | Std.Err. |     t | P>|t|
          ESG   | .0003697  | .0000564 |  6.55 | 0.000
       Leverage |-.0004685  | .0000685 | -6.84 | 0.000
      Ln Assets |-.0026387  | .0010409 | -2.54 | 0.011
CapitalIntensive| .0276779  | .0049454 |  5.60 | 0.000
          ROA   |-.0074588  | .0002338 | -31.91| 0.000
          Ln GDP| .0067168  | .0012215 |  5.50 | 0.000
          _cons | .2750809  | .0188432 | 14.60 | 0.000
```

Comment: Please [edit] to share the data as a table, instead of an image. Also, you'll need to post the commands used to generate each output.

Comment: I have put the results into table, can you help please?

Comment: Run `reg etr esg leverage lnassets capitalintensive roa lngdp, beta` in Stata and compare again (the column `Beta`).

Comment: Thank you , just did it and they are the same. Apprerciated

Answer (score 5):

Are you by chance comparing the standardized coefficients in SPSS to the non-standardized stata coefficients? The left-most column in both pictures contains non-standardized coefficients, and they are very close to each other (though in different order).

Comment: Thank you alot. I have discovered that i was looking on the unstandardized not the standardized. All i had to do in stata was to add to the command beta. APPRECIATED ALOT